# Pyhton Selenium No such Elements Everytings corrrect

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

I want to scrape the match results on [this website](https://www.iddaa.com/canli-skor) using Python and Selenium. The results are stored in the `tr` tags within a table, but I've tried several methods and haven't been able to locate the table or its elements. I am able to locate other parts of the page.I have also tried using class name and tag name, but none of them worked. Please help.

My code:

```
s = Service('C:/Users/Sezo/Desktop/verial/Selenium/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://www.iddaa.com/canli-skor")
table_xpath="/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/table"     
                 

table_id = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,table_xpath) 
print(len(table_id))
```

Comment: You have to wait until the page, ot at least the element, is loaded. See [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem there does not have to do with the waiting but with the iframe which is storing the information you are searching. Before extracting data there you have to change the context of the driver:

```py
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//iframe[contains(@class, "Iframe-sc")]'))
```

And then you can search for the element. I would use more deterministic XPATHs which are not so prone to errors:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[contains(@class, 'score')]")
```

Anyway you have to verify the xpaths by yourself and find something reliable.